# could not execute build using Gradle installation <gradle directory>

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, build.gradle

When I want to add play-sevices-locations-15.0.0.aar to my android project in android studio, error message below appears. How can I resolve it? regards.

[image]

Comment: Never post Errors as screenshots. Try updating the entire stacktrace block here in the question.

Comment: Could you also provide your Gradle files ?